# Nothing is printed from getElementByClass Jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have an online shop from which I need to get a set of products with specific parameters like name, price, description and so on after I search some kind of projects. Search is performed through keyword input. 
Here is a website: https://www.aboutyou.de/dein-shop. And this is the search I was trying to parse: https://www.aboutyou.de/frauen/accessoires/huete-und-muetzen/caps?pl=1

So I need to get all this data considering that in html source of the page there is a complex hierarchy of tags. I tried to get my elements by classes, except the highest one which is marked by the id and wrapped by the body.
So I tried to do something like this using jsoup:

```
lements resultt = doc.body().select("main#app");
    for(Element el : resultt){
        Elements main = el.getElementsByClass("section.layout_11glwo1-o_O-stretchLayout_1jug6qr > " +
                "div.content_1jug6qr > " +
                "div.container > " +
                "div.mainContent_10ejhcu > " +
                "div.productStream_6k751k > " +
                "div > " +
                "div.wrapper_8yay2a > " +
                "div.col-sm-6.col-md-4 > " +
                "div.wrapper_1eu800j > " +
                "div > " +
                "div.categoryTileWrapper_e296pg > " +
                "a.anchor_wgmchy > " +
                "div.details_197iil9 > " +
                "div.meta_1ihynio > " +
                "div.finalPrice_11ythok > " +
                "span.price_1543wg1");
        System.out.println("just print it" + main.text());
    }
```

But nothing is printed after "just print it" phrase. I know it is not a configuration problem as I tied to gem some information using higher level tags. What can I cahnge in my code to get this products entities information?
I am new to jsoup so I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the web page.

Comment: @TDG i have updated the question by adding links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace `Elements main = el.getElementsByClass("section.layout_11glwo1-o_O-stretchLayout_1jug6qr >...` with `el.select` you get a list of all prices:

> 17,90€ 19,90€ 19,90€ 24,90€ 19,90€ 24,90€ 24,90€ 19,90€ 17,90€ 19,90€ 17,90€ 49,90€ 39,90€ 39,90€ 17,90€ 19,99€ 39,90€ 19,99€ 34,95€ 17,90€

That's probably because the selector is not a class selector.

**EDIT**
this is the full code which works for me -

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.aboutyou.de/frauen/accessoires/huete-und-muetzen/caps?pl=1")
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0")
            .get();
    Elements result = doc.body().select("main#app");
    for(Element el : result) {
        Elements e = el.select("section.layout_11glwo1-o_O-stretchLayout_1jug6qr > " +
                "div.content_1jug6qr > " +
                "div.container > " +
                "div.mainContent_10ejhcu > " +
                "div.productStream_6k751k > " +
                "div > " +
                "div.wrapper_8yay2a > " +
                "div.col-sm-6.col-md-4 > " +
                "div.wrapper_1eu800j > " +
                "div > " +
                "div.categoryTileWrapper_e296pg > " +
                "a.anchor_wgmchy > " +
                "div.details_197iil9 > " +
                "div.meta_1ihynio > " +
                "div.finalPrice_11ythok > " +
                "span.price_1543wg1");
        System.out.println(e.text());
    }
```

Comment: When I change to select I still do not get anything printed

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I was trying to connect to another url. That is why I could not get anything.